# SQL Lastest Date per User - Eliminating Duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, max, solarwinds-orion

I have looked over 30 different ways to get the latest date from a joined table. Need help from the pros.

**Note:** 
- Using SolarWinds to create custom SQL reports
- Fairly new to SQL

I am trying to get a list of all my users with their username, primary group, name, and lastest logon date. This data is spread out between two tables.

The issue is that the current code I have is giving me a long list of duplicate users with the same date. I just need a list of all my users with their latest logon date.

This is the code that I came up with, it creates my report with no problem but still shows me duplicates, there is no grouping at all. What can i be missing?

```
SELECT
b.AccountName,
a.UserName,
b.PrimaryGroup,
b.MemberList,
a.LogonDateTime,
a.UserID

FROM UDT_UserLastActivity a

JOIN (
      SELECT UserID, MAX(LogonDateTime) maxLogon
      FROM UDT_UserLastActivity
      GROUP BY UserID
      ) maxRecord
ON maxRecord.UserID = a.UserID
AND maxRecord.maxLogon = a.LogonDateTime

JOIN UDT_User b
ON b.UserID = a.UserID

ORDER BY a.LogonDateTime DESC
```

Thanks in advance for anyone and everyone willing to help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Does `UDT_UserLastActivity` have a unique key?

Comment: You should at least show us sample data and point out what constitutes a duplicate.  I can guess at 2 or 3 causes right now, l but I can't answer.

Comment: Do yu need addtional columns from `UDT_UserLastActivity` besides `maxLogon`? Are `UserName` and `UserID` only available in this table?

Comment: Slight detour but something you should read. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3

Comment: @TabAlleman to be honest I don't know, this is my first time messing with SQL

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen like I stated above, a duplicate would show me the same user various times with the same date and time. Not sure if you are asking for something deeper.

Comment: @dnoeth UDT_UserLastActivity holds username and LogonDateTime which UDT_User does not. UDT_User holds my groups which is very important.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for sharing will read up! :)

Comment: Strange data model, `username` should be part of `UDT_User` or does it change so often?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just group by and search for max

```
SELECT
b.AccountName,
a.UserName,
b.PrimaryGroup,
b.MemberList,
max(a.LogonDateTime) as LastDate,
a.UserID

FROM UDT_UserLastActivity a

JOIN (
      SELECT UserID, MAX(LogonDateTime) maxLogon
      FROM UDT_UserLastActivity
      GROUP BY UserID
      ) maxRecord
ON maxRecord.UserID = a.UserID
AND maxRecord.maxLogon = a.LogonDateTime

JOIN UDT_User b
ON b.UserID = a.UserID
group by   
b.AccountName,
a.UserName,
b.PrimaryGroup,
b.MemberList,
a.UserID
ORDER BY a.LogonDateTime DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I tried the above with no avail. SQL does not query.

Comment: @JC1800  What error/problem do you get?  Just saying "It didn't work!" isn't very helpful

Comment: @iamdave in the solarwinds reporting console there is no log that gives you a specific error. Simply spits out "Query not valid". If there was an error I would have stated it

Comment: @JC1800 can you try to remove the order by?

Comment: @ClaudioBiselli THAT DID IT! :D Changed ORDER BY to LastDate and it's working exactly how I needed it! Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

*I just need a list of all my users with their latest logon date.*

Assuming that the basic data is in the users table and you only need the LogonDateTime from the activity table:

```
SELECT
   u.AccountName,  
   u.UserName,
   u.PrimaryGroup,
   u.MemberList,
   (-- Scalar subquery to get the last logon 
     SELECT MAX(LogonDateTime)
     FROM UDT_UserLastActivity AS ula
     WHERE ula.UserID = u.UserID
   ) AS LastLogon,
  u.UserID
FROM UDT_User AS u
ORDER BY LastLogon DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing dnoeth! I tried this but got a query not valid, going to try to find the issue!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the group by method as described above or you could just use the DISTINCT function, as below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  b.AccountName,
  a.UserName,
  b.PrimaryGroup,
  b.MemberList,
  a.LogonDateTime,
  a.UserID
 FROM UDT_UserLastActivity a
 JOIN (
  SELECT UserID, MAX(LogonDateTime) maxLogon
  FROM UDT_UserLastActivity
  GROUP BY UserID
 ) maxRecord
   ON maxRecord.UserID = a.UserID
     AND maxRecord.maxLogon = a.LogonDateTime
 JOIN UDT_User b
   ON b.UserID = a.UserID
 ORDER BY a.LogonDateTime DESC;
```

Also, if you are going to use the MAX() function you should be able to completely remove the subquery join for maxrecord, see below:

```
SELECT
  b.AccountName,
  a.UserName,
  b.PrimaryGroup,
  b.MemberList,
  MAX(a.LogonDateTime) as maxLogonDateTime,
  a.UserID
 FROM UDT_UserLastActivity a
 JOIN UDT_User b
   ON b.UserID = a.UserID
 GROUP BY b.AccountName,
  a.UserName,
  b.PrimaryGroup,
  b.MemberList,
  a.UserID
 ORDER BY MAX(a.LogonDateTime) DESC;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: this worked like a charm! Thanks so much for both of your solutions! You rock! :D